# How to plot streamplot with line density proportional to vector strength?

Tags: plotting

I try to use Lorentz transformation to plot electric field of a moving electron
based on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity.

I want to plot lines with density propotional to the local field, thus I wrote code as below.

```
r[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)
β[γ_] := (1 - γ^-2)^(1/2)
eFieldx0[x_, y_] := (x/r)/r^2 /. r -> r[x, y]
eFieldy0[x_, y_] := (y/r)/r^2 /. r -> r[x, y]
eFieldx[x_, y_, γ_] := eFieldx0[x, y]
eFieldy[x_, y_, γ_] := γ*eFieldy0[x, y]
γ = 2; xMax = 1;
StreamPlot[{eFieldx0[x, y], eFieldy0[x, y]}, {x, -xMax, xMax}, {y, -xMax, xMax}]
StreamPlot[{eFieldx[x, y, γ], eFieldy[x, y, γ]}, {x, xMax, xMax}, {y, -xMax, xMax}]
```

The second figure is shown as below, where line density seems not proportional to local field strength

[image]

I hope that the figure looks like below:

[image]

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `StreamPoints` may be useful here.